# Traveling salesman problem with dynamic edge costs

Tags: optimization

### General description

I have an optimization problem in which I need to schedule events and each of the events needs to be scheduled exactly once. The "cost" of scheduling one event depends on all of the events that have been scheduled before. So given a list of events $[e_1, e_2, ... e_n]$, the goal is to find an optimal order.

I think that this problem is similar to the traveling salesman problem - however, the cost of traveling between 2 cities depends on all the already visited cities. So while for the usual traveling salesman problem, the cost of visiting city k only depends on the previously visited city, i.e. $cost_k = f(k, k-1)$, in this case, the cost function needs to include all the visited cities, i.e. $cost_k = f(k, k-1, k-2, ..., 0)$.

So far, I couldn't find much information about such kind of problems. So my first question is if there is a common name for this class of problems that I could use to find more information. And of course, I would be very interested in any (approximate) solvers for such problem.

### Detailed explanation and formal description

The underlying problem is about placing some negative dosis (electrons) on exactly specified positions on a straight line where each electron that has been placed pushes away the newly arriving electrons leading to a misplacement. The order in which the dosis is placed is variable but the positions are fixed. The goal is to find an order of placing the dosis that leads to a minimal displacement.

E.g. when dosis needs to be placed at the positions $0$, $1$, $2$, the best solution is to start at position $0$, then go to position $2$ and place the dosis at position $1$ last. Due to symmetry of the force, there will be no misplacement at position $1$.

One can assume that the misplacement of the dosis is proportional to the force on the dosis and the force for placing dosis on position $y_k$ executed by the dosis already placed on position $y_j$ can be written as some signed gaussian function:
$$
F(y_k, y_j) = \text{sgn}(y_k - y_j) c_1 \exp(-c_2 (y_k-y_j)^2)
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants that do not depend on $y$, $k$ or $j$, and $\text{sgn}$ is the signum function. The total force on the $m$-th dosis can thus be written as
$$
F_m = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}|F(y_m, y_i)|
$$

So given the positions $\text{pos} = [y_0, y_1, \ldots, y_n]$, the objective is to find an optimal order of these positions such that the sum of the forces is minimal. The number of positions that need to be considered is in the order of $n=5000$.

Comment: What do you know about $f$? In particular, how do you specify $f$ so that the specification doesn't require exponential space?

Comment: The underlying problem is about placing electrons that push away each other. They are all on a straight line, so only one coordinate (y) needs to be considered. So the force of one electron on the other can be modeled by `g(y)` and the objective is to minimize the overall force. When placing an electron, the force gets smaller when placing it away from all other electrons or by using symmetry. So I get
`cost_k = g(y_k - y_k-1) + g(y_k - y_k-2) + ... + g(y_k - y_0)`
I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question, though.

Comment: Can you please state the physics problem formally in the post (for example, right now it's not clear why not just place the electrons infinitely far away)? TSP doesn't sound like a good way to think about it.

Comment: BTW, please use MathJax for math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for helping me to improve the question. I've updated the question and added a formal description of the (simplified) underlying problem.

Comment: How large is $n$?  How many electronics are you trying to place?  Also are $c_1,c_2$ the same for all pairs $j,k$, or do they depend on $j,k$?

Comment: The constants are the same for all pairs of $j$,$k$. $n$ can be in the order of 5000.

Comment: You probably want to minimize $\sum_{m} |F_m|$, not $\sum_{m} F_m$, correct?

Comment: Are you interested in a constant-factor approximation (e.g. returning the order which is, say, $10$ times worse than the optimal one)? I think that due to $\exp(-c_2 (y_k-y_j)^2)$ part it might be not too hard to achieve.